# Symfony2 / Twig : Split the parent definition

Tags: symfony, import, include, twig

I have a parent Twig file, which is extended at each page of my website.

**The problem is** :

- After a while, the parent is always too heavier, i need to split it
  into several parts (header, footer, blablabla),
- I can't use "include" because all the blocks definition will
  disappear,
- I can't use "use" because it's not made for that, and i need to redeclare all blocks definition => too heavy for the original objective,
- I can't use "macro" or "import" because, well, it's not macros. It's just a part of the parent file...
- I saw the "embed" tag but it won't work i think, i don't wan't to define a micro-inheritance.

All i want is simply retrieve blocks definition...a simple "require 'header.html.twig'", with its block definition...

This is a very important matter, so thanks for your help.

Comment: i cant follow you here ... you cant use include because blocks definition disappear? ... please explain that :)

Comment: As you can see in http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html, "The include statement includes a template and return the rendered content of that file". That means that all blocks in the included file are not retrieved, but alredy rendered. Include provide you pure html, not twig.

Comment: are you looking for a template hierarchy tree? just try to explain what you're trying to do ... you want to receive the twig template in it's non-processed form? where? in your controller? from database?

Comment: Not a tree. Example : the template of a page header. Generally, it has a banner, a menu, and a search toolbar (it's an example, but my case is almost the same).

Instead of having just one file (header.html.twig), I want to have : header_banner.html.twig, header_menu.html.twig, and header_search.html.twig, which are called in header.html.twig. Alongside, I want to preserve the blocks definition and keep it simple, like the require_once() method in PHP. It's just modularisation.

Comment: what do you mean by preserve blocks definition? how do they disappear? i can't follow. you can solve this using `include` or `render`.

Comment: Try this : Add {% block meta %}{% endblock %} into a file included with the "include" keyword - header.html.twig for example. The structure is now like this : page.html.twig [extends] layout.html.twig [include] header.html.twig. Now try to do {% block meta %}<meta name="author" content="Blabla">{% endblock %} in page.html.twig. It won't work.

Comment: ah i think i got it. you can't introduce new blocks in extending templates because your base template:  `layout.html.twig` does not know where to put them. you can't nest blocks either. in your example something like `{% block meta | default('') %}` has to be present in `layout.html.twig` in order to be able to override the block from `page.html.twig`. but you can include `header.html.twig` inside `{% block meta %}` from `page.html.twig` if the block is present in `layout.html.twig`.

Comment: Actually I found a way : {% use header.html.twig %}{% block header %}{{ parent() }}{% endblock %}. But : 1. It's made for reusability (not my case), 2. The code is pretty heavy. So that's why i'm here. Maybe I didn't understand the Twig way of thinking yet.

Comment: I guess the solution of my problem does not exists...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33116/discussion-between-chicna-and-nifr)